# Where can I find or donate software of historical interest?

Tags: repository, history

Computer science and programming is a field with a relatively short history but it is developing very rapidly.  Is there a repository for existing historical software or somewhere that I could submit software of historical interest?

I've asked this, and answered using the standard SO paradigm, because I thought it would be of general interest to the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am aware of only one repository for historical software, the [Software Preservation Group](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/).  It contains items of interest for [C++](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/c_plus_plus/), [LISP](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/LISP/), and [Fortran](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/FORTRAN/) among other topics.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try the [Computer History Museum](http://www.computerhistory.org/).

Comment: They don't really offer a repository for code, which was the intent of the question.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the exact type of software. Projects like the Multiple Arcade Machine Emulator (MAME) seek to preserve the processor-level instruction sets for specific arcade machine hardware, for example.

Answer (score 0):

[Trailing Edge Software](http://www.trailing-edge.com/) maintains **public-domain archives of vintage software**.  Although their front page makes them sound like they are interested in anything, their **actual collection seems limited to PDP-10 and PDP-11 codes**.  I expect the requirement that the software be in the public domain is fairly limiting.

Answer (score 0):

For my own code I just make it public on the web and then ensure the Internet Archive knows of the code. I do so by requesting the URL of it at http://web.archive.org/collections/web.html - after 12-24 months it then should appear at the Internet Archive.

Answer (score 0):

Google "Abandon Ware"